# No related set added from an abstract class with multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, foreign-keys, abstract-class

I have an issue to access the related data from a class which inherit from another.
My code (models.py) is below :

```
class AbstractTransaction(models.Model):
  compte            = models.ForeignKey(Utilisateur, 
    verbose_name='Compte', 
    related_name='%(class)s_set',
  )
  operateur         = models.ForeignKey(Utilisateur, 
    related_name='%(class)s_related',
    verbose_name='Opérateur', 
    editable=False,
  )

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Transaction(models.Model):
  quantite          = models.IntegerField('Quantité')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%i %s(s) pour %d' % (self.quantite, self.produit, self.cout)

class Operation(models.Model):
  commentaire       = models.TextField('Commentaires')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.quantite
```

And then I try to access my related transactions from an instance of Utilisateur like that

```
user = Utilisateur.objects.get(pk=1)
user.transaction_set.all()
```

But I get the error : 'Utilisateur' object has no attribute 'transaction_set'.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance,

Gabriel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably intended to subclass `AbstractTransaction`, but subclassed `models.Model`:

```
class Transaction(AbstractTransaction):
...
```

Comment: Oh. Sorry to bother you people. I was sure to have subclassed my models and forgot to check that.

Thanks !